# Weird behaviors of T-SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

For below data set I am trying to get the results where total of  Emp_AVG <> 100. Some how I am getting weird results in SQL Server based on the order of the Data in Emp_AVG column.

See below example:

```
drop table #temp1

select 'F_TEST1' as First_Name, 'L_TEST1' as Last_Name, 'P' as Emp_Catagory, '99.99' as Emp_AVG, 'JAN' as Emp_Month into #temp1 union all
select 'F_TEST1' as First_Name, 'L_TEST1' as Last_Name, 'C' as Emp_Catagory, '33.3' as Emp_AVG, 'FEB' as Emp_Month  union all
select 'F_TEST1' as First_Name, 'L_TEST1' as Last_Name, 'C' as Emp_Catagory, '33.3' as Emp_AVG, 'MAR' as Emp_Month  union all
select 'F_TEST1' as First_Name, 'L_TEST1' as Last_Name, 'C' as Emp_Catagory, '33.4' as Emp_AVG, 'APR' as Emp_Month  union all

select 'F_TEST2' as First_Name, 'L_TEST2' as Last_Name, 'P' as Emp_Catagory, '99.98' as Emp_AVG, 'JAN' as Emp_Month  union all
select 'F_TEST2' as First_Name, 'L_TEST2' as Last_Name, 'C' as Emp_Catagory, '33.3' as Emp_AVG, 'FEB' as Emp_Month  union all
select 'F_TEST2' as First_Name, 'L_TEST2' as Last_Name, 'C' as Emp_Catagory, '33.4' as Emp_AVG, 'MAR' as Emp_Month  union all
select 'F_TEST2' as First_Name, 'L_TEST2' as Last_Name, 'C' as Emp_Catagory, '33.3' as Emp_AVG, 'APR' as Emp_Month  union all

select 'F_TEST3' as First_Name, 'L_TEST3' as Last_Name, 'P' as Emp_Catagory, '99.97' as Emp_AVG, 'JAN' as Emp_Month  union all
select 'F_TEST3' as First_Name, 'L_TEST3' as Last_Name, 'C' as Emp_Catagory, '33.4' as Emp_AVG, 'FEB' as Emp_Month  union all
select 'F_TEST3' as First_Name, 'L_TEST3' as Last_Name, 'C' as Emp_Catagory, '33.3' as Emp_AVG, 'MAR' as Emp_Month  union all
select 'F_TEST3' as First_Name, 'L_TEST3' as Last_Name, 'C' as Emp_Catagory, '33.3' as Emp_AVG, 'APR' as Emp_Month  

--select * from #temp1

select First_Name,Last_Name, Emp_Catagory, sum(cast(Emp_AVG as float)) as Total_AVG
from #temp1
Group by First_Name,Last_Name, Emp_Catagory
having Sum(cast(Emp_AVG as float)) <> 100
order by sum(cast(Emp_AVG as float)) desc

/***************************************************************/
```

I will really appreciate if anyone can provide me the solution to this.

Regards,
Jigar B.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "weird results in SQL Server based on the order of the Data in Emp_AVG column". it might help if you add the actual and expected results to your question.

Comment: You didn't give a specification of the table, so I don't know what data type Emp_average is. And you didn't say what the weird results are, so until you do, it going to be hard to help you. But the first place I'd look is you are casting EMP_Average to float. Float is a binary storage type, not all decimal numbers can be stored exactly in it, so some rounding occurs. Search for the difference between decimal and float in SQL

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the "strange" result you're seeing is that there are results where `Total_AVG` seems to be equal to 100? Like this:

```
/---------------------------------------------------\
| First_Name | Last_Name | Emp_Catagory | Total_AVG |
|------------+-----------+--------------+-----------|
|  F_TEST2   |  L_TEST2  |      C       |   100     |
|  F_TEST3   |  L_TEST3  |      C       |   100     |
|  F_TEST1   |  L_TEST1  |      P       |    99.99  |
|  F_TEST2   |  L_TEST2  |      P       |    99.98  |
|  F_TEST3   |  L_TEST3  |      P       |    99.97  |
\---------------------------------------------------/
```

Try casting your values as `decimal` instead:

```
select 
    First_Name,
    Last_Name, 
    Emp_Catagory, 
    sum(cast(Emp_AVG as decimal(4,2))) as Total_AVG
from #temp1
group by 
    First_Name,
    Last_Name, 
    Emp_Catagory
having sum(cast(Emp_AVG as decimal(4,2))) <> 100
order by sum(cast(Emp_AVG as decimal(4,2))) desc
```

You then only see the results you are expecting:

```
/---------------------------------------------------\
| First_Name | Last_Name | Emp_Catagory | Total_AVG |
|------------+-----------+--------------+-----------|
|  F_TEST1   |  L_TEST1  |      P       |    99.99  |
|  F_TEST2   |  L_TEST2  |      P       |    99.98  |
|  F_TEST3   |  L_TEST3  |      P       |    99.97  |
\---------------------------------------------------/
```

Comment: Thank you for the Solution 3N1GM4, but I am still finding the route cause why float is behaving such and decimal is not ?